# Get all messages with info from service bus queue with powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azureservicebus

My question - is there some possibility of taking all messages from the service bus queue with all information like content and headers with PowerShell?

To take one I use
`$postService = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://myservice.servicebus.windows.net/test/messages/head"  -Headers $header -Method Post`

But it returns different messages I need the same or all list, and unfortunately, I do not find a way to do it with PS, but only with C# =/

Maybe someone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the [code](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/biz.dfch.PS.Azure.ServiceBus.Client/1.0.2.20160609/Content/Get-Message.ps1) and use `Get-Message` to get messages from Service Bus.

```
function Get-Message {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Receives a message from a receiver client, which is based on the Service Bus Messaging Factory.
 
.DESCRIPTION
Receives a message from a receiver client, which is based on the Service Bus Messaging Factory.
 
.OUTPUTS
This Cmdlet returns the Messaging Factory message object. In case of failure is trying '-Retry' times, otherwise returns $null.
 
.INPUTS
See PARAMETER section for a description of input parameters.
 
.EXAMPLE
Retrieves a message from ServiceBus. The message is immediately removed from the facility after receipt.
 
PS > Get-Message;
CorrelationId :
SessionId :
ReplyToSessionId :
DeliveryCount : 1
ExpiresAtUtc : 31.12.9999 23:59:59
LockedUntilUtc :
LockToken :
MessageId : e6dc938213264de790e53ace7949f610
ContentType :
Label :
Properties : {}
ReplyTo :
EnqueuedTimeUtc : 24.12.2015 21:00:00
ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc : 01.01.0001 00:00:00
SequenceNumber : 1
EnqueuedSequenceNumber : 0
Size : 6
State : Active
TimeToLive : 10675199.02:48:05.4775807
To :
IsBodyConsumed : False
 
.EXAMPLE
Retrieves a message from ServiceBus and save the message contents (body) to a variable. The message is immediately removed from the facility after receipt.
 
PS > $message = Get-Message -BodyAsProperty;
PS > write-host $message.Properties['Body']
I am a message body from ServiceBus with an arbitrary content.
 
.EXAMPLE
Similar to the previous example, but message is explicitly removed from the facility (in case the module default configuration is set to 'PeekLock').
 
PS > $message = Get-Message -ReceiveAndDelete -BodyAsProperty;
PS > write-host $message.Properties['Body']
I am a message body from ServiceBus with an arbitrary content.
 
.EXAMPLE
This example receives a message from the service bus. The message will be kept in the queue until it is explicity marked as 'Complete'
 
PS > $message = Get-Message -Receivemode 'PeekLock';
PS > # do something with the message before you acknowledge receipt
PS > $message.Complete();
 
.EXAMPLE
This example retrieves a message from the ServiceBus facility 'Topics-Newsletter'. The facility will be created if it does not exist.
 
PS > $message = Get-Message -Facility 'Topic-Newsletter' -EnsureFacility;
 
.EXAMPLE
Receives a message from a receiver client, which is based on the Service Bus Messaging Factory against server defined within module configuration xml file.
 
PS > $receiver = Get-MessageReceiver -Facility 'MyQueue1';
PS > $message = Get-Message -Client $receiver;
 
#>
[CmdletBinding(
    HelpURI = 'http://dfch.biz/biz/dfch/PS/AzureServiceBus/Client/'
)]
[OutputType([Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage])]
Param 
(
    # [Optional] The WaitTimeOutSec such as '3' Seconds for receiving a message before it times out. If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the default value = 3 sec.
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 0)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [int] $WaitTimeoutSec = [int]::MaxValue
    , 
    # [Optional] The Receivemode such as 'PeekLock'. If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the default parameter.
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)]
    [ValidateSet('PeekLock', 'ReceiveAndDelete')]
    [string] $Receivemode = 'ReceiveAndDelete'
    ,
    # [Optional] ReceiveAndDelete same as Receivemode 'ReceiveAndDelete'. If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the default parameter.
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)]
    [switch] $ReceiveAndDelete = $false
    ,
    # [Optional] ReceiveAndComplete same as Receivemode 'PeekLock' and $Message.Complete(). If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the default parameter.
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 3)]
    [switch] $ReceiveAndComplete = $false
    ,
    # [Optional] ReceiveAndAbandon same as Receivemode 'PeekLock' and $Message.Abandon(). If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the default parameter.
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 4)]
    [switch] $ReceiveAndAbandon = $false
    ,
    # [Optional] BodyAsProperty writes the Message Body to Property 'Body'. If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the default parameter.
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 5)]
    [switch] $BodyAsProperty = $false
    ,
    # [Optional] The Facility such as 'MyQueue'. If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the module configuration file.
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 6)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [alias("queue")]
    [alias("subscription")]
    [alias("QueueName")]
    [string] $Facility = (Get-Variable -Name $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.PrivateData.MODULEVAR -ValueOnly).ReceiveFacility
    , 
    # [Optional] Specifies if the facility will be created if it does not exist
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 7)]
    [alias("ensure")]
    [alias("broadcast")]
    [alias("checkfacility")]
    [switch]$EnsureFacility = $false
    ,
    # [Optional] Messaging Client (instance of the MessagingFactory)
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 8)]
    [alias("MessageClient")]
    $Client
    ,
    # [Optional] Skip retrying
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 9)]
    [switch]$NoRetry = $false
    ,
    # [Optional] The Retry. If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the module configuration file.
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position = 10)]
    [int]$Retry = (Get-Variable -Name $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.PrivateData.MODULEVAR -ValueOnly).CommandRetry
    ,
    # [Optional] The RetryInterval. If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the module configuration file.
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position = 11)]
    [int]$RetryInterval = (Get-Variable -Name $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.PrivateData.MODULEVAR -ValueOnly).CommandRetryInterval
)

BEGIN 
{
    $datBegin = [datetime]::Now;
    [string] $fn = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name;
    Log-Debug $fn ("CALL. Facility '{0}'" -f $Facility ) -fac 1;
    
    # Factory validation
    if((Get-Variable -Name $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.PrivateData.MODULEVAR -ValueOnly).Factory -isnot [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactory]) {
        $msg = "Factory: Factory validation FAILED. Connect to the server before using the Cmdlet.";
        $e = New-CustomErrorRecord -m $msg -cat InvalidData -o (Get-Variable -Name $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.PrivateData.MODULEVAR -ValueOnly).Factory;
        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($e);
    } # if

}
# BEGIN

PROCESS 
{

    [boolean] $fReturn = $false;

    # Get all parameters
    $Params = @{};
    $ParamsList = (Get-Command -Name $MyInvocation.InvocationName).Parameters;
    foreach ($key in $ParamsList.keys)
    {
        $var = Get-Variable -Name $key -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
        if($var)
        {
            if ( @('Retry', 'RetryInterval', 'NoRetry') -notcontains $($var.name) -and $var.value -ne $null -and $($var.value) -ne '' )  
            {
                $Params.Add($($var.name), $var.value);
            }
        }
    }
    #Log-Debug $fn ("Operation [{0}] arguments: {1}" -f ($fn -replace 'Worker', ''), ($Params | Out-String));
    
    # Retry handling
    for($c = 1; $c -le ($Retry+1); $c++)
    {
        try
        {
            $OutputParameter = Get-MessageWorker @Params;
            break;
        }
        catch
        {
            # Throw last execption
            if ( $NoRetry -or 
                $c -gt $Retry -or 
                $_.Exception.Message -match 'Connect to the message factory before using the Cmdlet.' -or
                $_.Exception.Message -match 'The message body cannot be read multiple times.'
                )
            {
                if ($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters["Debug"].IsPresent) 
                {
                    throw;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }    
            }
            Log-Debug $fn ("[{0}/{1}] Retrying operation [{2}]" -f $c, $Retry, ($fn -replace 'Worker', ''));
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $RetryInterval;
            $RetryInterval *= 2;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return $OutputParameter;
    $fReturn = $true;

}
# PROCESS

END 
{
    $datEnd = [datetime]::Now;
    Log-Debug -fn $fn -msg ("RET. fReturn: [{0}]. Execution time: [{1}]ms. Started: [{2}]." -f $fReturn, ($datEnd - $datBegin).TotalMilliseconds, $datBegin.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffzzz')) -fac 2;
}
# END

} # function
if($MyInvocation.ScriptName) { Export-ModuleMember -Function Get-Message; } 

function Get-MessageWorker {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Receives a message from a receiver client, which is based on the Service Bus Messaging Factory.
 
.DESCRIPTION
Receives a message from a receiver client, which is based on the Service Bus Messaging Factory.
 
.OUTPUTS
This Cmdlet returns the MessageId from the Messaging Factory message object. On failure it returns $null.
 
.INPUTS
See PARAMETER section for a description of input parameters.
 
.EXAMPLE
$message = Get-MessageWorker;
 
Receives a message from a receiver client, which is based on the Service Bus Messaging Factory.
#>
[CmdletBinding(
    HelpURI = 'http://dfch.biz/biz/dfch/PS/AzureServiceBus/Client/'
)]
[OutputType([Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage])]
Param 
(
    # [Optional] The WaitTimeOutSec such as '3' Seconds for receiving a message before it times out. If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the default value = 3 sec.
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 0)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [int] $WaitTimeoutSec = [int]::MaxValue
    , 
    # [Optional] The Receivemode such as 'PeekLock'. If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the default parameter.
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)]
    [ValidateSet('PeekLock', 'ReceiveAndDelete')]
    [string] $Receivemode = 'ReceiveAndDelete'
    ,
    # [Optional] ReceiveAndDelete same as Receivemode 'ReceiveAndDelete'. If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the default parameter.
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)]
    [switch] $ReceiveAndDelete = $false
    ,
    # [Optional] ReceiveAndComplete same as Receivemode 'PeekLock' and $Message.Complete(). If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the default parameter.
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 3)]
    [switch] $ReceiveAndComplete = $false
    ,
    # [Optional] ReceiveAndAbandon same as Receivemode 'PeekLock' and $Message.Abandon(). If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the default parameter.
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 4)]
    [switch] $ReceiveAndAbandon = $false
    ,
    # [Optional] BodyAsProperty writes the Message Body to Property 'Body'. If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the default parameter.
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 5)]
    [switch] $BodyAsProperty = $false
    ,
    # [Optional] The Facility such as 'MyQueue'. If you do not specify this
    # value it is taken from the module configuration file.
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 6)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [alias("queue")]
    [alias("subscription")]
    [alias("QueueName")]
    [string] $Facility = (Get-Variable -Name $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.PrivateData.MODULEVAR -ValueOnly).ReceiveFacility
    , 
    # [Optional] Checks if facility existing
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 7)]
    [alias("ensure")]
    [alias("broadcast")]
    [alias("CreateIfNotExist")]
    [switch] $EnsureFacility = $false
    ,
    # [Optional] Messaging Client (instance of the MessagingFactory)
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 8)]
    [alias("MessageClient")]
    $Client
)

BEGIN 
{
    $datBegin = [datetime]::Now;
    [string] $fn = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name;
    Log-Debug $fn ("CALL. Facility '{0}'" -f $Facility ) -fac 1;

}
# BEGIN

PROCESS 
{

[boolean] $fReturn = $false;

try 
{
    # Parameter validation
    if ( $ReceiveAndDelete ) 
    {
        $Receivemode = 'ReceiveAndDelete';
    }
    
    # Check facility
    if ( $EnsureFacility ) 
    {
        $Path = ($Facility -Split "\\Subscriptions\\")[0];
        $SubscriptionName = "RECV-{0}" -f (get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystemProduct  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UUID).toString();
        if ( $Facility -match "\\Subscriptions\\" )
        {
            $SubscriptionName = ($Facility -Split "\\Subscriptions\\")[1];
        }
        try 
        {
            $FacilitiyExists = New-MessageFacility -Path $Path -Name $SubscriptionName;
            $Facility = '{0}\Subscriptions\{1}' -f $Path, $SubscriptionName;
        } 
        catch 
        {
            $msg = $_.Exception.Message;
            Log-Error -msg $msg;
            $e = New-CustomErrorRecord -m $msg -cat InvalidData -o $Facility;
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($e);
        }
    }
    
    # Create Client
    if ( !$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Client') ) 
    {
        try 
        {
            $Client = Get-MessageReceiver -Facility $Facility -Receivemode $Receivemode;
        } 
        catch 
        {
            $msg = $_.Exception.Message;
            $e = New-CustomErrorRecord -m $msg -cat InvalidData -o $Client;
            Log-Error $fn -msg $msg;
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($e);
        }
    }
    
    # Get Message
    try 
    {
        # DFTODO - is this really an AMQP message when we are using the BrokeredMessage class?, see #5
        [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage] $BrokeredMessage = $Client.Receive((New-TimeSpan -Seconds $WaitTimeoutSec));
    } catch {
        $msg = $_.Exception.Message;
        $e = New-CustomErrorRecord -m $msg -cat InvalidData -o $BrokeredMessage;
        Log-Error $fn -msg $msg;
        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($e);
    }
    
    # Process Message
    if ( $BrokeredMessage -ne $null ) 
    {
        if ( $ReceiveAndAbandon -and $Receivemode -ne 'ReceiveAndDelete' ) 
        {
            $BrokeredMessage.Abandon();
        }
        
        if ( $ReceiveAndComplete -and $Receivemode -ne 'ReceiveAndDelete' ) 
        {
            $BrokeredMessage.Complete();
        }
        
        if ( $BodyAsProperty ) 
        {
            $PropertyName = 'Body';
            $PropertyValue = Get-MessageBody -Message $BrokeredMessage;
            if ( $BrokeredMessage.Properties.ContainsKey($PropertyName) -and $BrokeredMessage.Properties[$PropertyName].toString() -ne $PropertyValue.toString() ) 
            {
                [int] $PropertyCount = 1;
                $PropertyName = ("Body{0}" -f $PropertyCount);
                while( $BrokeredMessage.Properties.ContainsKey($PropertyName) )
                {
                    $PropertyCount += 1;
                    $PropertyName = ("Body{0}" -f $PropertyCount);
                }
            }
            $BrokeredMessage.Properties[$PropertyName] = $PropertyValue;
        }
    }
    
    $OutputParameter = $BrokeredMessage;
    $fReturn = $true;
}
catch 
{
    if($gotoSuccess -eq $_.Exception.Message) 
    {
            $fReturn = $true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        [string] $ErrorText = "catch [$($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId)]";
        $ErrorText += (($_ | fl * -Force) | Out-String);
        $ErrorText += (($_.Exception | fl * -Force) | Out-String);
        $ErrorText += (Get-PSCallStack | Out-String);
        
        if($_.Exception -is [System.Net.WebException]) 
        {
            Log-Critical $fn "Login to Uri '$Uri' with Username '$Username' FAILED [$_].";
            Log-Debug $fn $ErrorText -fac 3;
        }
        else 
        {
            Log-Error $fn $ErrorText -fac 3;
            if($gotoError -eq $_.Exception.Message) 
            {
                Log-Error $fn $e.Exception.Message;
                $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($e);
            } 
            elseif($gotoFailure -ne $_.Exception.Message) 
            { 
                Write-Verbose ("$fn`n$ErrorText"); 
            } 
            else 
            {
                # N/A
            }
        }
        $fReturn = $false;
        $OutputParameter = $null;
    }
}
finally 
{
    # Clean up
    # N/A
}
return $OutputParameter;

}
# PROCESS

END 
{
    $datEnd = [datetime]::Now;
    Log-Debug -fn $fn -msg ("RET. fReturn: [{0}]. Execution time: [{1}]ms. Started: [{2}]." -f $fReturn, ($datEnd - $datBegin).TotalMilliseconds, $datBegin.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffzzz')) -fac 2;
}
# END

} # function
```

Comment: The module 'biz.dfch.PS.Azure.ServiceBus.Client' cannot be installed or updated because the authenticode signature of the file 'biz.dfch.PS.Azure.ServiceBus.Client.psd1' is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a .NET wrapper for this which exposes PowerShell cmdlets that can be called natively from PowerShell. The repository can be found
at https://github.com/sumanthvrao/AzurePowerShellCmdlets.

Once you have imported the dlls, you can connect and fetch a message from the service bus topic using the `Get-ServiceBusMessage` cmdlet like

```
$message = Get-ServiceBusMessage -connectionString $env:connString -topicName "test" -subscriptionName "abc"
```